# compare an ID in array of arrays and take only a single row with the date in desc order in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arrayofarrays

I have an array like this :

```
$data = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'UserID' => '1',
    'ShipPinCode' => '411008',
    'createdDate' => '2011-10-04 01:16:54.723',
    'Amount' => '1000.00',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'UserID' => '1',
    'ShipPinCode' => '411008',
    'createdDate' => '2011-10-04 01:24:24.243',
    'Amount' => '1000.00',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'UserID' => '102818',
    'ShipPinCode' => '500072',
    'createdDate' => '2011-11-29 12:17:43.880',
    'Amount' => '2000.00',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'UserID' => '100001',
    'ShipPinCode' => '500072',
    'createdDate' => '2011-11-26 11:49:17.760',
    'Amount' => '2000.00',
  ),
);
```

I want to sort it in such a way that for duplicate entries of UserID the final output should contain only a single row for that UserID where the createdDate is the largest i.e in descending order.

Desired output :

```
array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'UserID' => '1',
        'ShipPinCode' => '411008',
        'createdDate' => '2011-10-04 01:24:24.243', //only took one row of UserID 1 where the createdDate is the largest.
        'Amount' => '1000.00',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'UserID' => '102818',
        'ShipPinCode' => '500072',
        'createdDate' => '2011-11-29 12:17:43.880',
        'Amount' => '2000.00',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'UserID' => '100001',
        'ShipPinCode' => '500072',
        'createdDate' => '2011-11-26 11:49:17.760',
        'Amount' => '2000.00',
      ),
    );
```

I'm not able to figure out how to do the comparison in such a case.
How do I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Have you seen the usort function in PHP? Looks what you are looking for. https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php

Comment: to get the output like $data I used various array functions like array_combine and array_merge. But regarding the desired output I'm not able to figure how to exactly proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort ascending by the `createdDate`:

```
array_multisort(array_column($data, 'createdDate'), SORT_ASC, $data);
```

Then you can extract and index on `UserID` which will only keep the last one:

```
$result = array_column($data, null, 'UserID');
```

If you want to reindex (not needed):

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: whoa this is perfect :). please suggest me some good reads regarding advanced php array concepts